# innerHTML strips classes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with HTML, that I am trying to push inside an empty div. The new div should acquire all the content and styling from the original.

Existing content:

```
<ul id="existing_id" class="my_class">
  <strong>Does not show up in new div</strong>
  <li class="style">
    <p class="style">Shows up in new div</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

New, empty div - where I push everything from "existing_id" into:

```
<div id="empty_div"></div>
```

I am targeting the elements through JS:

```
var existing = document.getElementById("exisiting_id")
var existing_li = existing.getElementsByTagName("li")
var empty_div = document.getElementById("empty_div")
var myArray = []

empty_div.innerHTML = ""

// Pushing each existing li element inside myArray
for (var i=0; i < existing_li.length; i++) { myArray.push(existing_li[n]; }

function make_it_happen() {
  empty_div.innerHTML += myArray.innerHTML
}
```

I am getting the content from `#existing_id` inside the new div - but not the styling associated with each element. Some elements are also ignored such as `<strong>Does not show up in new div</div>`

Comment: You're building an array of DOM elements. There will be no `.innerHTML` property on that array. You should be building an array of the `.innerHTML` of each separate `<li>`, and just append the concatenation of all those strings.

Comment: Your whole code example is full of smaller errors, that will prevent it from even running in this form. So at least provide a _working_ example of what you are actually doing. // As for the `strong` element not “showing up” – well, kinda natural when you only select `li` elements to loop over in the first place, don’t you think? And btw., having a `strong` at that point in a `ul` would be invalid HTML.

Comment: And why you are not using just `empty_div.innerHTML = existing.innerHTML` in the first place is a mystery that you owe us an explanation for as well … (You might have chosen the approach looping over elements for a reason – but what that is, you failed to mention.)

Comment: @Pointy that is the mistake I was making. Thank you. Not only was I building an array of DOM elements, I wasn't concatenating the output properly.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for pointing out the markup errors. That was a typo I made when typing out the question. The above scenario was intentionally shortened and vague hoping to prevent a long messy ask. Perhaps it did the opposite. The longer code, grabs each list element and passes them individually into an array. From that array there is another function printing out X number of those elements to the page, simulating pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to collect all of the HTML from all of the LI elements into empty_div, you don't need myArray.  The following should do:

```
var existing = document.getElementById("existing_id")
var existing_li = existing.getElementsByTagName("li")
var empty_div = document.getElementById("empty_div")

function make_it_happen() {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < existing_li.length; i++) {
      html += existing_li[i].innerHTML;
  }
  empty_div.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I appreciate it. I tried running this script in a test scenario and couldn't get the existing content into the empty div. http://jsfiddle.net/nxsq2ors/

Comment: Sorry, I had a couple of typos in my original (for example, exisiing instead of existing). I corrected it above, and created this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/q4zptrxg/